# ng4 How do I redirect the user to Login page after an error occurred?

Tags: angular

How do I redirect the user to Login page after an error occurred ?

My code is given below.

```
// Function for settting the default restangular configuration
export function RestangularConfigFactory (RestangularProvider, authService) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://api.test.com/v1');

  // This function must return observable
  var refreshAccesstoken = function () {
    // Here you can make action before repeated request
    return authService.functionForTokenUpdate();
  };

  RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {
    if (response.status === 403) {

      refreshAccesstoken()
      .switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {
        //If you want to change request or make with it some actions and give the request to the repeatRequest func.
        //Or you can live it empty and request will be the same.

        // update Authorization header
        response.request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + refreshAccesstokenResponse)

        return response.repeatRequest(response.request);
      })
      .subscribe(
        res => responseHandler(res),
        err => subject.error(err)
      );

      return false; // error handled
    }
    return true; // error not handled
  });
}

// AppModule is the main entry point into Angular2 bootstraping process
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ 
    // Importing RestangularModule and making default configs for restanglar
    RestangularModule.forRoot([authService], RestangularConfigFactory),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend `Http` to handle the errors. In our case when we send the 401 from the server we also send a redirect address on the response body, you can do something else if you choose.

`@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }
  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.handleErrors) as Observable<Response>;
  }
  handleErrors(response: Response): ObservableInput<string> {
    const body = response.json();
    if (response.status === 401 && body.redirect) {
      window.location.href = body.redirect;
    }
    return Observable.throw(body.Message || 'Request failure');
  }
}`

Then create a factory to export the http service wrapper

`export function _httpServiceFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
  return new HttpService(backend, defaultOptions);
}`

In your providers at the root of your app provide for `Http` with your factory. 
`{
  provide: Http,
  useFactory: _httpServiceFactory,
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}`

Comment: You meant I should use `window.location.href` for setting up redirection URL?? does it work with any issue??

Comment: We chose to go with window.location.href because it was a very easy, fast, and low level navigation, we were not worried about closing the app gracefully for unauthorized access.  You can use any response status or caught error to redirect, we just chose to do it on `401`. For us `500` errors are handled on the individual api's.

Comment: The observable itself for ‘http’ will throw the error for non success responses. At that point you can decide how deep you want to go. This helps explain a little more https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Comment: `window.location.href` Worked like a charm. I had to admit things with ng1 are quite straightforward.